# Why is double 0.1 more accurate than its long double version?

Tags: numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy, long-double

How can I understand this another floating-point paradox --- 0.1 represented as double is more accurate than 0.1 represented as long double?

```
In [134]: np.double(0.1)
Out[134]: 0.1

In [135]: np.longdouble(0.1)
Out[135]: 0.10000000000000000555
```

Comment: `Decimal(np.double('0.1'))` gave me `Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')`, which may be just a printing problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not more accurate. The longdouble repr is just showing you more of the inaccuracy that was already present.

`0.1` is a Python float, which has the same precision as `numpy.double`. It does not represent the exact decimal value 0.1, because binary cannot represent that value in a finite number of bits. `0.1` represents this value:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(0.1)
Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')
```

which is the closest value to 0.1 that can be represented within the limits of the type's precision.

When you construct a `numpy.double` or `numpy.longdouble` from `0.1`, this is the value you get. For `numpy.longdouble`, this is *not* the best approximation of 0.1 the type could store.

The `repr` of both `numpy.double` and `numpy.longdouble` show the minimum number of decimal digits needed to produce an output that will reproduce the original value if converted back to the original type. For `numpy.double`, that's just `"0.1"`, because `0.1` was already the closest double-precision floating point value to 0.1. For `numpy.longdouble`, it requires more digits, because `numpy.longdouble` has more precision, so it can represent values closer to 0.1 than `0.1`.

If you want the best long double approximation of 0.1, you should pass a string instead of a Python float:

```
numpy.longdouble('0.1')
```